# Can't install laravel on Debian 8 (64-bit)

Tags: laravel, debian

I was trying to install larval on a debian server and got this error.

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
```

I tried to install php7.2-zip and then got this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.2-zip is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libuuid-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
```

it says ext-zip already exists. But laravel says it doesn't exist

Comment: just because it is "installed" doesn't mean it is "enabled"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is to do with PHP as such but instead the Laravel Installer. I had this issue before and I can't remember exactly but I can point you in the 'relative' direction which worked for me. From what I remember, I had to install laravels 1.0 installer, and then it would update itself from there which fixed my issue. Just my resolution, could work for you, I hope :)